# Where jwt access token is stored in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**Hello Everyone**

i am working on spring boot project with jwt authentication and spring security ,
i could get access token but have a big problem .
it is
**where access token exactly stored?**
i mean (in-memory database , cache or something els)

thanks

Comment: It isn't stored somewhere, it is the task of the client to send it along with the request in the Authorization header.

Comment: no , but where the token i send with requests get validation that it is ture

Comment: Inside the Spring Security filter code - if you configure it to do so. A process which is documented just fine, if you want to know how it works... go read the Spring Security documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It is stored [in-memory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2ClientConfigurerUtils.java#L94) by default.

#### Clients

If you are an OAuth 2.0 Client, you can retrieve the token in a controller using [the `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-registered-authorized-client), like so:

```java
@GetMapping("/data")
public String data(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient client) {
    String accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    // ...
}
```

Or, if you need it at the service layer, then you can retrieve it from the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService`.

Note, though, that if you are needing the access token in order to propagate it downstream, you can instead [configure the `WebClient` with Client's `ExchangeFilterFunction`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/webclient/src/main/java/example/WebClientConfiguration.java#L44) that will lookup, refresh, and propagate the token for you.

#### Resource Servers

If you are an OAuth 2.0 Resource Server, you can retrieve it directly from the `Authentication`.

Here's what that looks like [in the controller](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/resource-server/hello-security/src/main/java/example/OAuth2ResourceServerController.java#L34):

```java
@GetMapping("/data")
public String data(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt) {
    String accessToken = jwt.getTokenValue();
    // ...
}
```

Note, though, that if you are needing the access token in order to propagate it downstream, you can instead [configure the `WebClient` with Resource Server's `ExchangeFilterFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#bearer-token-propagation) that will lookup and propagate the token for you.